# Adding a custom dialogue box to Google Forms Editor using Ui services

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google form that I would like to add a custom dialogue box that contains a text box and a text area. I do not want to use html services, as I do not want to add an extra page to the script. I am a bit confused on how to go about this and would appreciate if someone could post an example. Accord to the method documentation I could use:

```
var ui = FormApp.getUi();
ui.showModalDialog(userInterface, title);
```

But I am unsure how to build the userInterface part here using the Ui services. I.E.

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function showUi() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var txtBox = app.createTextBox().setId('txtBox').setName('txtBox');
  var txtArea = app.createTextBox().setId('txtArea').setName('txtArea');
  panel.add(txtBox).add(txtArea);
  app.add(panel);
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(app, 'Your title');
}
```

You've seen the [documentation for UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app), right?
Why not use HtmlService?

Comment: Yep saw the documentation. The example was only with html services, so it threw me off a bit. I want to only have one sheet of code to copy over. It should be as easy as possible for other non technical people to copy the code into another form editor and authorize it. HTML Services requires the extra step of creating another sheet, then pasting in code in another area. I don't find it necessary to add the extra complications.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Ui Elements (either from UiApp Service or HTML Service to a form when this form is published (the user filling the form seeing the added elements) then you simply can't.

The referenced documentation you show is all about adding an Ui to the form "design" interface, the one you use to create the form. In this one you can add a sidebar or show popups or modal popups.

In this last case and using the elements you presented it is very straightforward :

```
var ui = FormApp.getUi();
var app = UiApp.createApplication();// add any widgets to this...
ui.showModalDialog(app, 'Your title'); // for example, to show a modal popup, showSideBar to show a sidebar.
```

Comment: The other answer (Bryan) was there while I was answering so I stopped writing the full example... I let my answer here just for the part about use cases...;-)

Comment: wasn't sure if it was about just building one for the editor or using it in the deployed form